# How do I get YAML in Ruby as of 1.9.3 to dump ASCII-8Bit strings as strings?

Tags: ruby, string, utf-8, binary, yaml

Here's the problem: I might have strings that are UTF-8, and I might have strings that are US-ASCII. Regardless of the encoding, I'd like YAML.dump(str) to actually dump `String` objects, instead of these useless `!binary` objects as the example shows.

Is there a flag or something I'm not seeing to force YAML.dump() to do the right thing?

**Ruby 1.9.1 example**

```rb
YAML::VERSION              # "0.60"
a = "foo"                  # => "foo"
a.force_encoding("BINARY") # => "foo"
YAML.dump(a)               # => "--- foo\n"
```

**Ruby 1.9.3 example**

```rb
YAML::VERSION              # "1.2.2"
a = "foo"                  #  => "foo" 
a.force_encoding("BINARY") #  => "foo" 
YAML.dump(a)               # => "--- !binary |-\n  Zm9v\n"
```

**Update: Got my own answer**

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler='syck'
YAML.dump(a)               # => "--- foo\n"
```

So, looks like using the old yamler engine with force the old behavior.

Comment: Why are you forcing the encoding to `BINARY` in the first place?

Comment: Because sometimes I'm dealing with binary strings, like "\xFE\xFF\x00\x00" and I don't want UTF-8isms.

Comment: Besides, here, it's just an example. My real use case is slightly more complicated :)

Comment: I mean, I don't know much about YAML, but I'd say that this isn't something that would be wise to fight. The latter is definitely doing the right thing, since binary is binary, not ASCII. Storing binary as a string is misleading, especially given all the character encoding weirdness. Also, why is the binary format useless?

Comment: The "!binary" format is useless in my case because a Java consumer down the line doesn't know that !binary really means "binary string"

Comment: And honestly, I'm not interested in YAML's judgement calls on my String data. I put a string in with whatever encoding, and I should get a string out. This is a violent change which (after perusing other StackOverflow questions) is surprising to say the least.

Comment: If you've found your answer, please post it as an answer rather than editing your question with it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not do something like `YAML.dump(a.to_s)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update: Got my own answer**

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler='syck'
YAML.dump(a)               # => "--- foo\n"
```

Comment: Forcing an obsolete YAML parser globally is not a good way to go, would love to get more answers on this question